# Javascript Pie Chart in Django App - Problems displaying dynamic data

Tags: javascript, django, charts

I can't figure this out: I've got a Django application, and I have a little JavaScript code on the index page's template to make a pie chart. I don't really know JavaScript, but got a bit of code from somewhere and it works. My problem is, the code works when when I type the data in directly, but when I try to get the data dynamically, the pie chart disappears.

The thing that confuses me is that, when I look at the page source, the data is *there*. It has successfully pulled it from the database and put it in the correct format for the chart data. So it looks like it should be working.

Below I have the page source: the first lines of data are the dynamically-produced ones, then the ones after that (that are commented out) are the statically-typed ones. If I comment out the dynamic ones, and un-comment the static ones, the pie chart is there. Vis-versa, and it disappears. The two sets of data look exactly the same to me -- what's going one?

```
$(function () {
    // data
    var data = [

        { label: "Blogs",  data: 87102},

        { label: "Conversation (Phone)",  data: 2652},

        { label: "Folktales",  data: 47981},

        { label: "Internet Forums",  data: 75900},

        { label: "Jokes",  data: 5833},

        { label: "Literature",  data: None},

        { label: "Opinion",  data: 19231},

        { label: "Plays",  data: 9512},

        { label: "Poem",  data: 404},

        { label: "Political Speeches",  data: 733},

        { label: "Proverbs",  data: 1081},

        { label: "Radio",  data: 13774},

        { label: "Recipes",  data: 215},

        { label: "Songs",  data: 3161},

        { label: "Sports",  data: 8732},

        { label: "Television (Drama)",  data: 142029},

        { label: "Web",  data: 336919},

        // { label: "Web",  data: 337972},
        // { label: "Television",  data: 142029},
        // { label: "Blogs",  data: 86049},
        // { label: "Internet Forums",  data: 74058},
        // { label: "Folktales",  data: 30698},
        // { label: "Opinion",  data: 19231},
        // { label: "Plays",  data: 9512},
        // { label: "Sports",  data: 8732},
        // { label: "Radio (News)",  data: 7438},
        // { label: "Radio (Interviews)",  data: 6286},
        // { label: "Jokes",  data: 5833},
        // { label: "Songs",  data: 3161},
        // { label: "Conversation (Phone)",  data: 2652},
        // { label: "Proverbs",  data: 1081},
        // { label: "Political Speeches",  data: 733},
        // { label: "Poem",  data: 404},
        // { label: "Recipes",  data: 215},
        // { label: "Radio (Listener Responses)",  data: 53},

    ];
```

Here's the full code for the chart, in case you need it:

```
{% block javascript %}
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/media/js/flot/jquery.flot.js"></script>
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/media/js/flot/jquery.flot.pie.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    // data
    var data = [
        {% for cat,count in cat_wordcount %}
        { label: "{{ cat }}",  data: {{ count }}},
        {% endfor %}
        // { label: "Web",  data: 337972},
        // { label: "Television",  data: 142029},
        // { label: "Blogs",  data: 86049},
        // { label: "Internet Forums",  data: 74058},
        // { label: "Folktales",  data: 30698},
        // { label: "Opinion",  data: 19231},
        // { label: "Plays",  data: 9512},
        // { label: "Sports",  data: 8732},
        // { label: "Radio (News)",  data: 7438},
        // { label: "Radio (Interviews)",  data: 6286},
        // { label: "Jokes",  data: 5833},
        // { label: "Songs",  data: 3161},
        // { label: "Conversation (Phone)",  data: 2652},
        // { label: "Proverbs",  data: 1081},
        // { label: "Political Speeches",  data: 733},
        // { label: "Poem",  data: 404},
        // { label: "Recipes",  data: 215},
        // { label: "Radio (Listener Responses)",  data: 53},

    ];

    var series = Math.floor(Math.random()*10)+1;

    // GRAPH 7
     $.plot($("#graph7"), data,
    {
            series: {
                pie: {
                    show: true,
                    combine: {
                        color: '#999',
                        threshold: 0.03
                    }
                }
            },
            legend: {
                show: false
            }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is at

```
{ label: "Literature",  data: None},
```

None is not a valid js expression

Edit: To avoid the None problema you should have something like this at your template:

```
{ label: "{{ cat }}",  data: {% if count %} {{ count }}} {% else %} 0 {% endif %},
```